# Detect when Ajax request to search page returns 0 results before displaying HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get json code from page.I use this

```
private function __ajax_admin_search($username = '')
{
   $result = $this->admin_login->Admin_Username_Ajax($username);
   $count = count($result);
   for ($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++)
      $arr[$i] = $result[$i]->username;
   echo (json_encode($arr));
}
```

And try to show it by jQuery and JavaScript

```
$("#AdminSearch").bind("change keyup", function() { 
           var url = "http://localhost/PmMusic/index.php/admin/ajax/admin_search/"+$("#AdminSearch").val();
            $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                if (data.length == 0) // or arr == null
                {
                    $("#AutoSearch").hide(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#AutoSearch").show(1000);    
                }
            });

        });
```

Now my problem is,I can't detect when __ajax_admin_search doesn't find any result and first if (in JavaScript) doesn't be TRUE(always it's FALSE). 
how Can I detect in JavaScript when my php code doesn't find any result in database.

Comment: If the page doesn't echo anything, then can't you just check whether or not the `data` variable is empty?

Comment: You are checking something within a JavaScript variable `arr` which is not the same as you PHP variable `arr`. You will find your data (when returned by PHP) within the JavaScript variable `data`. Then you should also initialize all variables instead of relying on PHP's guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to initialise `$arr = Array();` before your `for` loop.

Then, the PHP script will return `[]` as the JSON object, which you can detect in JavaScript without problems.

Answer (score -1):

be aware that you have to set the correct mime type. your javascript is expecting json so you need to set the headers in php. The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json...

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: when we use getJSON in jQuery,it means that get json code,and it will convert it to array in javascript type.

Comment: getJSON is a shorthand function for an AJAX call with dataType:'json'. if you echo json encoded data you have to set the appropriate mime type or your jquery does not see this as json. I had this problem before and solved it with setting the correct header.